# Cannot retrieve JSON POST via PHP: cURL

Tags: php, json, post, curl, force.com

I tried implementing the following PHP code to POST JSON via PHP: cURL (SOME FORCE.COM WEBSITE is a tag that signifies the URL that I want to POST):

```
$url = "<SOME FORCE.COM WEBSITE>";

$data =
'application' =>
array
(
    'isTest' => FALSE,
    key => value,
    key => value,
    key => value,
    ...
)

$ch = curl_init($url);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
//Send blindly the json-encoded string.
//The server, IMO, expects the body of the HTTP request to be in JSON
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
array
(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
)
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);

echo '<pre>';
echo $_POST;
$jsonStr = file_get_contents('php://input'); //read the HTTP body.
var_dump($jsonStr);
var_dump(json_decode($jsonStr));
echo '</pre>';
```

The output of the above is the following:

```
"Your TEST POST is correct, please set the isTest (Boolean) attribute on the application to FALSE to actually apply."
Arraystring(0) ""
NULL
```

OK, the above confirms that I formatted the JSON data correctly by using json_encode, and the SOME FORCE.COM WEBSITE acknowledges that the value of 'isTest' is FALSE. However, I am not getting anything from "var_dump($jsonStr)" or "var_dump(json_decode($jsonStr))". I decided to just ignore that fact and set 'isTest' to FALSE, assuming that I am not getting any JSON data because I set 'isTest' to TRUE, but chaos ensues when I set 'isTest' to FALSE:

```
[{"message":"System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Missing body, need at least one of html or plainText: []\n\nClass.careers_RestWebService.sendReceiptEmail: line 165, column 1\nClass.careers_RestWebService.postApplication: line 205, column 1","errorCode":"APEX_ERROR"}]
Arraystring(0) ""
NULL
```

I still do not get any JSON data, and ultimately, the email was unable to be sent. I believe that the issue is resulting from an empty email body because there is nothing coming from "var_dump($jsonStr)" or "var_dump(json_decode($jsonStr))". Can you help me retrieve the JSON POST? I would really appreciate any hints, suggestions, etc. Thanks.

Comment: Check your response's headers, like Content-type!

Comment: Where is $jsonStr ? Where do you assign it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question on my own. I was not sure if I was doing this correctly or not, but it turns out that my code was perfect.  I kept refreshing my website, from where I am POSTing to SOME FORCE.COM WEBSITE. I believe that the people managing SOME FORCE.COM WEBSITE were having issues on their end. Nothing was wrong with what I did. For some reason, I got a code 202 and some gibberish text to go along with it. I would be glad to show the output, but I do not want to POST again for the sake of the people managing SOME FORCE.COM WEBSITE that I am POSTing to. Thank you guys for your help.